# How to connect graphql server to postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, graphql

This is my`posgres.sql` file in my project directory:

```
CREATE TABLE client (
  cli_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  cli_name text NOT NULL,
  cli_birthyear smallint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE product (
  pro_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  pro_ean text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  pro_name text NOT NULL,
  pro_description text NOT NULL,
  pro_weight_g smallint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE command (
  com_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  com_number text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  cli_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES client
);

CREATE TABLE command_line (
  lin_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  com_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES command,
  pro_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES product,
  lin_quantity smallint NOT NULL
);
```

Now, how do I use this file to `connect the postges database to graphql`? And how query postgres database using graphql?

Comment: You need to write a program to do that.  GraphQL and SQL are different things and PostgreSQL doesn't (and shouldn't) provide a GraphQL interface to its data store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect GraphQL and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940528/how-to-connect-graphql-and-postgresql)