# how to connect postgresql with graphql

Tags: postgresql, graphql

I have a table in my database in postgres. The table name is "mytable" and it has 4 columns: name, post, country, contact. I can show the column values in browser with nodejs. Here is the code :

```
const pg        = require('pg');
const express   = require('express');
const app       = express();


const config = {
    user: 'test',
    database: 'mydatabase',
    password: '1234',
    port: 5432
};

const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    pool.connect(function(err,client,done) {
       if(err){
           console.log("not able to get connection "+ err);
           res.status(400).send(err);
       } 
       client.query("SELECT * FROM mytable",function(err,result) {
           done(); 
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
               res.status(400).send(err);
           }
           res.status(200).send(result.rows);
       });
    });
});

app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running.. on Port 4000');
});
```

I want to show the values in browser with Graphql. How to do this?

n.b I am very new to graphql. I've done some research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940528/how-to-connect-graphql-and-postgresql) and [here](https://blog.cloudboost.io/postgresql-and-graphql-2da30c6cde26), but cannot understand properly. Thanks

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicate questions. An existing question may have no answers or its answers may be lacking in quality, but posting duplicate questions only degrades the quality of the site by making it harder for people to search for answers.

Comment: You should probably start by following any of the tutorials available out there on how to set up a simple GraphQL server in node. That and review the relevant documentation. Once you can set up a GraphQL server and understand how GraphQL works, you can start integrating it with Postgres. If you encounter specific issues during this process, you can search SO for questions about similar issues. If a question hasn't been asked on the site, then it would be appropriate to start a new post for it.